# Giving users ability to view their password (type=text), chrome giving DATA BREACH error

Tags: php, html, forms, passwords

I'm giving users the ability to view their password as they type it. From my understanding the best way to do this is change type="text" and type="password".

However, crome is giving an error on login "Change your password, A data breahc on a site or app exposed your password".

Is this just because I am on a development server without SSL? Or am I doing it the wrong way?

Answer (score 2):

Nothing to worry about your development. This happens because Google Chrome checks if your password has been stolen/breached from an EXTERNAL website. Check the news regarding this feature:

- https://www.blog.google/products/chrome/better-password-protections/

You are probably using a "dev" password such as "test123". Therefore Chrome believes you are using such password in production or a real account.

Answer (score 0):

Try to enter some difficult password which is not common.